# Kafka Streams: Proper way to exit on error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've been successful in getting a streams app to consume, transform and produce data, but I've noticed that periodically, the streams processor will transition to a state of `ERROR` and the process will sit there without exiting.

Showing me logs like:

`All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.`

Is there a way to tell the Streams app to exit once its reached the `ERROR` state? Maybe a monitor thread of sorts?

I see [references](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.java#L190-L191) in the comments of the Kafka Streams code to the user needing to close the application once its reached this state, however, I haven't been able to find mention of this task in the documentation.

Is there a simple way to do this shutdown step?

---

### probably incorrect way to potentially close on errors

My intention was to set the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` method on the `KafkaStreams` object, to do the following:

- log the error
- shutdown the stream using the `close` method on the original `KafkaStreams` object

What results from that is:

- message for the exception is logged
- `INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams ... State transition from ERROR to PENDING_SHUTDOWN`
- `INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread ... Informed to shut down`

And then, unfortunately the process seems to hang without exiting.

FWIW I feel like this is probably a misuse of the `setUncaughtExceptionHandler`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is correct. However, if you call `KafkaStreams#close()` within the handler call-back you can run into a deadlock. Thus, you should either only set a flag, and call `#close()` outside of the callback, or you use `close()` with a timeout. If the timeout expires, a shutdown is forced.

Comment: This definitely helped! I also found that including a latchCountDown right afterwards helped to close it all down.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - could You be more specific with example :D

Comment: This example use a latch in the shutdown hook. But you can do the same in the exception handler: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pipe/PipeDemo.java